# URL of the website from which the user access my website in grails

Tags: url, grails, http-referer

I have a website developed in Grails, it is available from other sites. In my code (in beforeInterceptor), I want to get the URL of the site from which the user access my website. I know we can do this using request.getHeader ("referer") but I'm not sure that the referer header is always made ​​up (can be disabled in the browser config for security reasons).
How can I do this differently?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There're no other way. If user has disabled `referer` header you cannot find out where from he came.